# Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'vgg16_input_4' with dtype float and shape [?,32,32,3]

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tf.keras, vgg-net

I got following error

> InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.   (0) Invalid argument:
>   You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'vgg16_input_4' with
>   dtype float and shape [?,32,32,3]      [[{{node vgg16_input_4}}]]
>   [[dense_6/Softmax/_1775]]   (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a
>   value for placeholder tensor 'vgg16_input_4' with dtype float and
>   shape [?,32,32,3]      [[{{node vgg16_input_4}}]] 0 successful
>   operations. 0 derived errors ignored.

and following code

```
def show_result(n):

    samples = []
    for i in range(n):
        original_img = x_test[i]
        print('original_img->',original_img.shape)

        img_array = np.expand_dims(original_img, 0)
        #img_array = original_img


        print('img_arrray->', img_array.shape)
        #tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img_array, dtype=tf.float16, saturate=False)

        get_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input], [model.layers[-3].output, model.layers[-1].output])
        [conv_outputs, predictions] = get_output([img_array])

        conv_outputs = conv_outputs[0, :, :, :]
        class_weights = model.layers[-1].get_weights()[0]

        cam = np.zeros(dtype = np.float32, shape = conv_outputs.shape[0:2])
```

the shape of the image is

> original_img-> (32, 32, 3) img_arrray-> (1, 32, 32, 3)

```
model = models.Sequential()

base_model = VGG16(include_top = False, input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
base_model.layers.pop()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=1024, kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: your _img_array_ is with shape (1, 32, 32, 3) while get_output([img_array]) you are again adding _img_array_ to list, which is making shape (1,1,32,32,3)

Comment: so which line should I change to what? kind of confused

Comment: try: _get_output(img_array)_ instead of _get_output([img_array])_